# Subsonic3 Active Record Query using SubSonic.Query.Select throwing errors

Tags: c#, .net, activerecord, subsonic, subsonic3

So I am trying to get the following query to work using SubSonic3 ActiveRecord with a Sql Server 2008 backend

```
facilities = new Select().From<Facility>()
             .ExecuteTypedList<Facility>();
```

as well as the following

```
facilities = new Select().From<Facility>()
                .InnerJoin<mem_Users_Facility>().InnerJoin<mem_User>().Where(mem_UsersTable.UserNameColumn).IsEqualTo(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User)
                .ExecuteTypedList<Facility>();
```

The Table name is dbo.Facility but SubSonic keeps generating the SQL as Facilities.  The class was generated by SubSonic so it knows what the table name is but it looks like the SQL is getting generated as if the class is used in the Simple Repository (based off of a POCO).

I know that I can use the Linq query syntax but I am more familiar with the old syntax and want to be able to use both.  How can I write the two simple queries with Subsonic3

Comment: I am using 3.0.0.3.  Well I am actually using the latest source code.  As this is a new project I have changed the database schema naming structure to camel case with plural table names.  Active Record has no way to get to the ITable definition of the table so the query just tries to assume your schema as if it were SimpleRepository instead of ActiveRecord which knows the schema as it was generated.